# interface IComparer C#

Tags: c#, generics

как правильно реализовать IComparer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IComparable` добавить

```
public class RoomComparerByVolume<T> : IComparer<T> where T : IShape, IComparable
{
    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```